# Integer comparison in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to implement something like:

```
if [ $i -ne $hosts_count - 1] ; then
    cmd="$cmd;"
fi
```

But I get

> ./installer.sh: line 124: [: missing
>   `]'

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `[` can't handle arithmetics inside its test. Change it to:

```
if [ $i -ne $((hosts_count-1)) ]; then
```

**Edit:** what @cebewee wrote is also true; you **must** put a space in front of the closing `]`. But, just doing that will result in yet another error: `extra argument '-'`

Answer (score 4):

1. The `]` must be a separate argument to `[`.
2. You're assuming you can do math in `[`.

   ```
   if [ $i -ne $(($hosts_count - 1)) ] ; then
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but why I need to use double [[ ? @pepoluan answer also works, without double [[.

Comment: Well, you don't *need* to, but `[[` will let you have unquoted empty variables without causing problems.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can avoid both `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` by using `(( ))` for purely arithmetic conditions:

```
if (( i != hosts_count - 1 )); then
  cmd="$cmd"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing `]` needs to be preceded by a space, i.e. write

```
if [ $i -ne $hosts_count - 1 ] ; then
    cmd="$cmd;"
fi
```